# async, await - это ключевые слова? С точки зрения модуля keyword - нет!

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await

В Python 3.5 добавили ключевые слова `async, await` (согласно PEP 492 - Coroutines with async and await syntax). Но это не нашло отражения в модуле keyword. Так, код

```
import keyword
for kword in keyword.kwlist:
   print(kword)
```

выдает следующее:

```
False
None
True
and
as
assert
break
class
continue
def
del
elif
else
except
finally
for
from
global
if
import
in
is
lambda
nonlocal
not
or
pass
raise
return
try
while
with
yield
```

То есть это ошибка или `async, await` не стали ключевыми словами?

Comment: По крайней мере переменные async и await успешно создаются как обычно)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Соседний ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/759939/181100) не вполне верен. **Это вовсе не ошибка.** Они действительно не являются *полноценными* ключевыми словами **до Python 3.7**, и об этом [прямо сказано в PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#deprecation-plans):

> #### Deprecation Plans
>
> `async` and `await` names will be softly deprecated in
>   CPython 3.5 and 3.6. In 3.7 we will transform them to proper keywords.
>   Making `async` and `await` proper keywords before 3.7 might make it harder
>   for people to port their code to Python 3.

> #### Планы по устареванию
>
> Идентификаторы `async` и `await` будут мягко обозначены устаревшими в CPython 3.5 и 3.6. В 3.7 мы сделаем их полноценными ключевыми словами. Становление `async` и `await` полноценными ключевыми словами до 3.7 может обернуться для людей сложностями в портировании кода на Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Это ошибка но она уже исправлена в комите https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/ac317700ce7439e38a8b420218d9a5035bba92ed

Comment: У меня 3.6 версия. Что так сложно было им исправить модуль?
Это ж как нужно автору модуля забыть о Python, чтоб не исправить список ключевых слов?
Модуль то еле на курсовую тянет по сложности

Comment: @VasylKolomiets это не случайность и не забыто, это было запланировано на время перехода: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#deprecation-plans

Comment: не баг, а фича.